# Android: Ensuring listview takes up full activity

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

In my app there is an activity that will show the results of users answers for multiplications. 
The activity is working as intended however the list view is not taking up enough of the screen and therefore looks poor. 
I want the listview to take up as much room as possible and still have the text view at the top of the page that displays score to be visible. 
I have tried using android weightsum in the xml but it doesnt seem to be working.

I am also wondering how to change the title at the top of the screen from "Multapply" (the apps name) to "Results"?

Current activity (note amount of free space under listview):

[image]

corresponding xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/tvRandomTestresults"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >

        </TextView>

    <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/lvRandomTestresults"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Set the `android:layout_weight="1"` attribute and set `android:layout_height="0"`

Comment: For which one? can u please provide me with more info

Comment: I meant the `ListView`. You'll probably have to the same to the `TextView` setting it some weight to make both `View`s proportional.

Comment: This has not worked, it does not change the amount of blank space below the listview

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView 
       android:id="@+id/lvRandomTestresults"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1" />
```

To fill up most of the space, you will prob need to make the font bigger or add more padding to each `ListView row`.

As for the title bar being renamed to `Results`:

you can either change it in the Android manifest by finding the `android:label` tag in the activity it is in and change that string to what you want.

or you can do it programmatically in the code with `getActionBar().setTitle("Results");` or `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Results");` (if you are using the appcompat_v7).

Comment: Ur answer in reference to the listview has not worked?

Comment: @RNI2013 that should have worked in terms of filling up the entire space. If you wanted all the rows to be expanded to fill up the entire space, play with the padding for the `ListView row xml`, ie. add some more padding to it (specifically the top and bottom).